# Prove inequality of probabilities

Tags: inequality

I want to prove the following inequality:

$$x_{1}y_1 +x_2y_2 \geq x_{3}y_3 + x_{4}y_4  $$

where

- $x_i, y_i \in\ ]0,1[$ and
- $x_1>x_3$
- $x_2>x_4$
- $y_1>y_3$
- $y_2>y_4$

I tried to substract $x_3y_3$ from $x_1y_1$, and $x_4y_4$ from $x_2y_2$, but I am not sure if this is the right way to prove it.

Comment: You just need to observe that $x_1y_1>x_3y_3$ follows from the inequalities you have above,and similarly for the other indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All thae variables $\in [0,1]$
$$x_1> x_3$$
$$y_1> y_3$$
$$\implies x_1y_1 >x_3y_3 ~~~(1)$$

Similarly
$$x_2 >x_4$$
$$y_2 >y_4$$
$$\implies x_2y_2 >x_4 y_4~~~~(2)$$
Adding (1) andd (2) we get
$$x_1y_1+x_2y_2>x_3y_3+x_4 y_4$$

Answer (score 1):

$x_1y_1+x_2y_2>x_3y_1+x_4y_2 >x_3y_3+x_4y_4$.